# How do make a get request using php and then access it using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I need to make a get request to google places api however I can't use just javascript because it does not support jsonp. I read that I could do a get request using a php file and then do a normal jquery ajax call to that in order to get the json data. However I created the php file using

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("https://maps.google...");
?>
```

and then using a jquery ajax request to this file hosted on my http:localhost/ server on my ubuntu distro, yet i am getting a 500 http server error. What am I doing wrong or how do I go about doing this correctly?

```
</script>

      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

      $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/places.php',
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      success: function( data){
      document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML= data.result[0].name;
      },
      error: function(request, status, error){
      document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML= "error";
      }
      })


      });

</script>
    <body>
    <p id="paragraph">
       Untouched Text.
    </p>
    <button id="b1">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
```

The only error message I get using firebug is 500 Internal Server Error so I don't think its my html, javascript, or jquery.

Comment: Can you post the full code of your PHP file. Also enable error reporting and tell us what errors you are getting.

Comment: It would be useful to see your whole code. Could you possibly paste your JavaScript here too?

Comment: Do you think it may be that Im not including the places api within my php file?

Comment: Thats all I have in my php file, the code I got it from only had the echo statement and the file_get_contents call. What do I need to add to it in order for it to send back the json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling Google API and must return a JSON, so this ought to be enough:

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false");

    $data = json_decode($json);

    // manipulate data and rebuild json with $json = json_encode($data) if needed

    Header("Content-Type: application/json");
    die($json);
?>
```

This works, in that Google answers me with a correctly formed, if succinct, JSON:

```
{

    "results": [ ],
    "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

With proper API Key configuration you ought to get this working. Check that the call is working in your browser (without cookies, etc. - a clean session, which is what `file_get_contents()` is going to give you) and that your PHP installation is capable of recovering SSL data (it should, but let's check), i.e.,

```
file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/");
```

ought to recover Google's home page.

This call needs no authentication (there's a rate limit, but I think it's unlikely you'll be making all the calls required to get you shut out):

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false
```

The above will return a *very* complex JSON with possibly accented characters in. Now that I come to think of it, the `Header` above would be better like this:

```
    Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: Ok so that eliminated the php but I am getting the same error as you saying the REQUEST_DENIED.

Comment: You are issuing either a wrong call, or a call that needs authentication (an API Key). I'm adding a 'simple' call to my answer as an example.

Comment: I wouldn't need to include the google places api within the php file right? I know for the javascript file I do but I don't think it would be necessary since the api is in javascript right?

Comment: Nevermind I got the Get request to go through but it is not successful and runs the error function instead...